# ngx-toastr giving error c.Subject is not a constructor when angular app is being served by nginx using dist

Tags: angular, toastr

I have an angular app and the home page is a template from Bootstrapmade.com. The template is edited to include ngx-toastr and I show some pop-ups.
If I run the same code on localhost via `ng serve`, it is working fine. But if I create dist using `ng build --prod`, then the same toastr code is giving error as

```
​ ERROR TypeError: c.Subject is not a constructor
    at new e (main.42af73f….js:1:1336551)
    at e.value (main.42af73f….js:1:1340579)
    at e.value (main.42af73f….js:1:1338410)
    at e.sendMail (/9.1239612….js:1:86136)
    at /9.1239612….js:1:136416
    at Xu (main.42af73f….js:1:712642)
    at r (main.42af73f….js:1:712804)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (main.42af73f….js:1:1077547)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.e071be3….js:1:8982)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main.42af73f….js:1:814856)
```

Code is below

```
if(isInvalid === true){
this.toaster.error('Please provide the correct email ids. Please separate multiple email ids with a comma (,).','Invalid Email Ids',{
          closeButton:true,        
          tapToDismiss: false,
          positionClass: 'toast-top-center'
        });
}
```

Below is the output of ng version

```
Angular CLI: 11.2.0
Node: 14.18.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 11.2.1  animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms 
material, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
platform-server, router, upgrade`

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1102.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1102.0
@angular-devkit/core            11.2.0
@angular-devkit/schematics      11.2.0
@angular/cli                    11.2.0
@angular/http                   7.2.0-beta.2
@schematics/angular             11.2.0
@schematics/update              0.1102.0
rxjs                            6.6.3
typescript                      4.1.5
```

I tried looking for solution on internet, but nothing was helpful.

`import { Subject } from "rxjs";`
is already added.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Ahead of Time compilation is doing it, see if this occurs when you serve the app as production:

```
ng serve --prod
```

also, you can troubleshoot this disabling Ahead of Time compilation:

```
ng build --prod --aot=false
```

Comment: Hi Tal,
You are right, I tried what you suggested. 
ng serve --prod  -> I see the issue with this.

I tried making aot false, but it asked me to make buildoptimizer as false to proceed. Following was the error.

Option "extractCss" is deprecated: 
An unhandled exception occurred: The 'buildOptimizer' option cannot be used without 'aot'.
--
I made buildOptimizer false and then did ng build --prod --aot=false
With this I do not see the issue.
But for production build, can I make buildOptimizer  and aot false? Should we have a better solution?

Comment: Below is my current config.
"production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": false,

Comment: buildOptimizer and optimization options are for build time and build size reduction, see the next link https://intsights.com/labs/blog/angular-build-optimizations